# Display multiple images on dialog with data from file (C++ MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm practice with MFC, but I have some problems.
Display a map render from txt file, like this:

```
4 4 //size_of_map
1 1 2 3
2 3 1 3
3 1 1 2
2 2 1 3
```

..with 1 = river image, 2 = tree image, 3 = rock image...
But I don't know how to display multiple images with Picture Control.
The map can resize by data input then I can't create 16 Picture Control.
How can I manage and create multiple images as number of input file?

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use controls/windows for each picture. Use one view / window and handle the drawing in `OnDraw`/`OnPaint`.

Store all pictures in one image list. Use `CImageList` Draw to draw one image. You can easily use indexing to draw the imaged from the image list.

Comment: I'm just beginning with MFC. Try to search about what you said but I still don't understand it completely... Can you give me some example?

Comment: You find enough samples for the keywords "OnDraw/OnPaint" and CImageList. Just use Google. This are basic techniques.